# jUnit and DateFormat (EclEmma code coverage)

Tags: java, junit, junit4, emma, eclemma

I'm new to jUnit and I'm trying to deep more my knowledge about it. I searched on the web but didn't found anything to solve a couple of doubts.

This is the code:

```
public class StringConverter {

    public static String formatDate(Date date) {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return sdf.format(date);
    }

}
```

This is the jUnit4 Test Case:

```
public class StringConverterTest {

    @Test
    public void testFormatDate() {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 02, 13, 8, 30, 00);
        assertEquals("13/03/2013 08:30:00", StringConverter.formatDate(calendar.getTime()));
    }

}
```

The TestCase runs correctly without any problems but i have 2 simple questions/problems:

1) It's correct to test only the correct functionality of the method or should i test also `null` values and/or any particular exception?

2) When i run the code coverage with **EclEmma** it gives me 75% code coverage because the test case is not testing the constructor of the `StringConverter` class. Testing the `StringConverter` class constructor is not in my plan since the `StringConverter` class is a util class, so it won't be instanced. There is a way to exclude this from the code coverage?

Any advice wil be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To make sure that your method is bullet-proof, you should test every possible way to call it that you can think of, including with a `null` argument, unless you place a dire warning on the code that says:

   > DO NOT EVER CALL THIS CODE WITH A `null` ARGUMENT.
2. If it is a utility class with only static methods, the no-argument constructor should be `private` and the class should be `final`, to emphasize this fact. Then maybe [emma](/questions/tagged/emma) will leave you alone, especially if this constructor is empty.

Comment: Since the method is not called depending on 3rd part data, better to be solid at 100%. For the EclEmma problem, i tried your suggestion but still showing not coverage to 100% due to the missing of the constructor. Regarding the code coverage about private constructor is a well-know problem so i think i'll stay with a not 100% code coverage. Thanks.